# Java Rest sending data

Tags: java, rest, service

Can you please help me with sending data (mp3, wav etc.) using Rest service?  I dont know what mime type should I use in my service method declaration.

I have something like this:

```
>
```

`@Path("/echo") public class MyService{
   @GET 
   @Produces("text/html") 
   public String get(@Context UriInfo ui) {
      MultivaluedMap queryParams=ui.getQueryParameters();
      return "tyleczek";      
   }

   @POST
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   @Produces("text/html") 
   public String post(MultivaluedMap queryParams) {
     return showQueryParams(queryParams);    
   } 
}`

> I triend sending it as byte code but it didnt work. Can you please help me?
>   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually binary content is transferred after being encoded in Base64. Check [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) Base64 for a ready-to-use implementation